# How many $A_{m,n}$ are possible where elements belong to $[10]\times [10]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $A_{m,n}$ denote the set $$A_{m,n}=\{(m,n),(m+2,n), (m, n+2), (m+2, n+2)\}$$ where $m,n$ are integers.

I want to determine the number of A_{m,n},  with all their element belonging to $[10]\times [10]$

Efforts:

It is clear to me that $m\leq 8$ otherwise $m+2$ will exceed 10 and similarly $n\leq 8$

So there are 64 elements.

Am I right? How should I approach this problem?(In case I am wrong)

Thanks.

Comment: It is correct.........